# Dependency injection in @NgModule not working Angular2 2.1.0

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I am trying to correctly set up @NgModule in the latest Angular2 2.1.0. I have some injectable code that relies on other injectable code, and the dependence is not getting initialized for some reason.

When the app starts I get the following error: `core.umd.js:3076 TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTokenPromise' of undefined at Object.tokenGetter (app.module.ts:68)`

The undefined object in this case is `unifiedLogin` in the line `return unifiedLogin.getTokenPromise();`

I expected that UnifiedLogin login would have been injected into AuthHttp and initialized but it is not.

This is a fairly large project so I am only including what I hope are the relevant code fragments.

This is the section of my @NgModule statement that is in question from app.modules.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AuthHttp, AuthConfig } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { UnifiedLogin } from './unified-login';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

...

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        AppRoutingModule
    ],
    providers: [
        UnifiedLogin,
        {
            provide: AuthHttp,
            useFactory: (http: Http, unifiedLogin: UnifiedLogin) => {
                return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
                    tokenGetter: (() => {
                        return unifiedLogin.getTokenPromise();
                    })
                }), http);
            },
            deps: [UnifiedLogin]
        }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is the UnifiedLogin code that I expected to be initialized and injected into AuthHttp but wasn't

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

...

@Injectable()
export class UnifiedLogin {

    ... 

    public getTokenPromise(): Promise<string> {
        return this._storage.get('id_token');
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to list the dependencies in `deps` that you use in the `useFactory` function. Since you only list `deps: [UnifiedLogin]`, the `UnifiedLogin` gets passed as the first argument to the `useFactory` function, and the second argument gets nothing.

You should add the `Http` to `deps` so the arguments are resolved accordingly

```
{
    provide: AuthHttp,
    useFactory: (http: Http, unifiedLogin: UnifiedLogin) => {
        return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
            tokenGetter: (() => {
                return unifiedLogin.getTokenPromise();
            })
        }), http);
    },
    deps: [Http, UnifiedLogin]   <====== Http
}
```